# Facebook Total Shares count not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using total shares count PHP scripts provided by donReach.com at github project.

Problem - Every other count service working perfect except facebook counts. It is always displaying 0 counts.

But if I use their API url to check my any url shares which is https://count.donreach.com/?url=http://www.twistblogger.com/2015/04/floating-social-media-share-buttons-bar-blogger-total-share-count.html

Its shows all the counts perfectly.

So my question is what is the problem at my end? I used the same PHP scripts and uploaded to http://codefreak.hol.es/?url=http://www.twistblogger.com/2015/04/floating-social-media-share-buttons-bar-blogger-total-share-count.html as per the guidelines but it did not work the way it is supposed to be .

Below is the Share count code:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
class shareCount {
    private $config;
    private $data;
    private $url;
    private $format;
    private $callback;
    private $cache;
    private $cache_directory;
    private $cache_time;

    function __construct() {
        $this->config = new Config;
        $this->cache = $this->config->cache;
        $this->cache_directory = $this->config->cache_directory;
        $this->cache_time = $this->config->cache_time;
        $this->data = new stdClass;
    }

    private function getVar($var, $strict = false) {
        if(array_key_exists($var, $_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST[$var] !== "") return $_REQUEST[$var];
        elseif($strict) return false;
        else return $this->config->$var;
    }

    public function get($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->data->url           = $this->url;
        $this->data->shares        = new stdClass;
        $this->data->shares->total = 0;

        return $this->getShares($url)->shares;
    }

    public function serve() {
        $this->url = $this->url ?: filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

        // kill the script if no URL provided
        if(!$this->url) die("Error: No URL specified.");

        $this->setFormat($this->format ?: $this->getVar('format'));
        $this->callback            = $this->callback ?: $this->getVar('callback');
        $this->data                = new stdClass;
        $this->data->url           = $this->url;
        $this->data->shares        = new stdClass;
        $this->data->shares->total = 0;

        $data = $this->getData();
        return $data;
    }

    // set format of the output
    private function setFormat ($format) {
        switch($format) {
            case "xml":
                $this->format = 'xml';
                header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
                break;
            case "jsonp": 
                $this->format = 'jsonp';
                header ("Content-Type: application/javascript"); 
                break;
            case "json": // only here for reference
            default:
                if($this->getVar('callback', true)) {
                    $this->format = 'jsonp';
                    header ("Content-Type: application/javascript"); 
                }
                else {
                    $this->format = 'json';
                    header ("Content-Type:application/json");
                }
        }
        return $format;
    }

    // query API to get share counts
    public function getShares($url = '') {
        $url = $url ?: $this->url;

        $shareLinks = array(
            "facebook"    => "https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?format=json&urls=",
            "twitter"     => "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=",
            "google"      => "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=",
            "linkedin"    => "https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?format=json&url=",
            "pinterest"   => "http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=",
            "stumbleupon" => "http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=",
            "delicious"   => "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url=",
            "reddit"      => "http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?&url=",
            "buffer"      => "https://api.bufferapp.com/1/links/shares.json?url=",
            "vk"          => "https://vk.com/share.php?act=count&index=1&url="
        );

        foreach($shareLinks as $service=>$provider) {
            @$this->getCount($service, $provider . $this->url);
        }

        switch($this->format) {
            case 'xml':
                return $this->generateValidXmlFromObj($this->data, "data");
            case 'json':
            case 'jsonp':
                return json_encode($this->data);
            default:
                return $this->data;
        }
    }

    // query API to get share counts
    private function getCount($service, $url){
        if(function_exists('curl_version')) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'shareCount/1.1 by abemedia');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
        else {
            $data = @file_get_contents($url);
        }

        $count = 0;
        if ($data) {
            switch($service) {
            case "facebook":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = (is_array($data) ? $data[0]->total_count : $data->total_count);
                break;
            case "google":
                preg_match( '/window\.__SSR = {c: ([\d]+)/', $data, $matches );
                if(isset($matches[0])) $count = str_replace( 'window.__SSR = {c: ', '', $matches[0] );
                break;
            case "pinterest":
                $data = substr( $data, 13, -1);
            case "linkedin":
            case "twitter":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = $data->count;
                break;
            case "stumbleupon":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = $data->result->views;
                break;
            case "delicious":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = $data[0]->total_posts;
                break;
            case "reddit":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                foreach($data->data->children as $child) {
                    $ups+= (int) $child->data->ups;
                    $downs+= (int) $child->data->downs;
                }
                $count = $ups - $downs;
                break;
            case "buffer":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = $data->shares;
                break;
            case "vk":
                $data = preg_match('/^VK.Share.count\(\d+,\s+(\d+)\);$/i', $data, $matches);
                $count = $matches[1];
                break;
            default:
                // kill the script if trying to fetch from a provider that doesn't exist
                die("Error: Service not found");
            }
            $count = (int) $count;
            $this->data->shares->total += $count;
            $this->data->shares->$service = $count;
        } 
        return;
    }

    // Get data and return it. If cache is active check for cached data and create it if unsuccessful.
    private function getData() {
        if($this->cache) $key = md5($this->url) . '.' . ($this->format == 'jsonp' ? 'json' : $this->format);
        switch($this->cache) {
            case 'memcache':
                if(!function_exists('memcache_connect')) 
                { 
                    die('Memcache isn\'t installed'); 
                } 
                else
                {
                    $memcache = new Memcache;
                    $memcache->addServer($this->config->cache_server, $this->config->cache_port, $this->config->cache_persistent);
                    if(!$memcache->connect($this->config->cache_server, $this->config->cache_port)) 
                    { 
                        die('Couldn\'t connect to Memcache host'); 
                    } 
                    $data = $memcache->get($key);
                    if ($data === false) {
                        $data = $this->getShares();
                        $memcache->set($key, $data, $this->cache_time);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'apc':
                if (apc_exists($key)) {
                    $data = apc_fetch($key);
                }
                else {
                    $data = $this->getShares();
                    apc_store($key, $data, $this->cache_time);
                }
                break;
            case 'file': 
                $data = $this->getCacheFile($key);
                break;
            default:
                $data = $this->getShares();
        }
        // if the format is JSONP wrap in callback function
        if($this->format == 'jsonp') $data = $this->callback . '(' . $data . ')';

        return $data;
    }

    // get cache file - create if doesn't exist
    private function getCacheFile($key) {
        if (!file_exists($this->cache_directory)) {
            mkdir($this->cache_directory, 0777, true);
        }
        $file = $this->cache_directory . $key;
        $file_created = ((@file_exists($file))) ? @filemtime($file) : 0;
        @clearstatcache();
        if (time() - $this->cache_time < $file_created) {
            return file_get_contents($file);
        }
        $data = $this->getShares();
        $fp = @fopen($file, 'w'); 
        @fwrite($fp, $data);
        @fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    }

    // Delete expired file cache. Use "kill" parameter to also flush the memory and delete all cache files.
    public function cleanCache($kill = null) {
        // flush memcache
        if($kill) {
            switch($this->cache) {
                case 'memcache':
                    $memcache = new Memcache;
                    $memcache->flush();
                    break;
                case 'apc':
                    apc_clear_cache();
                    apc_clear_cache('user');
                    apc_clear_cache('opcode');
                    break;
            }
        }
        // delete cache files
        if ($handle = @opendir($this->cache_directory)) {
            while (false !== ($file = @readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != '.' and $file != '..') {
                    $file_created = ((@file_exists($file))) ? @filemtime($file) : 0;
                    if (time() - $this->cache_time < $file_created or $kill) {
                        echo $file . ' deleted.<br>';
                        @unlink($this->cache_directory . '/' . $file);
                    }
                }
            }
            @closedir($handle);
        }
    }

    // output share counts as XML
    // functions adopted from http://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2009/03/turning-an-array-or-object-into-xml-using-php/
    public static function generateValidXmlFromObj(stdClass $obj, $node_block='nodes', $node_name='node') {
        $arr = get_object_vars($obj);
        return self::generateValidXmlFromArray($arr, $node_block, $node_name);
    }

    public static function generateValidXmlFromArray($array, $node_block='nodes', $node_name='node') {
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
        $xml .= '<' . $node_block . '>';
        $xml .= self::generateXmlFromArray($array, $node_name);
        $xml .= '</' . $node_block . '>';
        return $xml;
    }

    private static function generateXmlFromArray($array, $node_name) {
        $xml = '';
        if (is_array($array) || is_object($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
                if (is_numeric($key)) {
                    $key = $node_name;
                }
                $xml .= '<' . $key . '>' . self::generateXmlFromArray($value, $node_name) . '</' . $key . '>';
            }
        } else {
            $xml = htmlspecialchars($array, ENT_QUOTES);
        }
        return $xml;
    }
}
</code>
```

For the facebook counts this script uses

```
"https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?format=json&urls=",
```

But in that case it even did not show facebook count option at all then I replace https to http and facebook count started showing but always remain zero. I have also tried changing it with graph.facebook.com/?id= but the results were same.

I never used PHP scripts and I don't know anything about PHP but I'll try my best as per your suggestions.

Please guide me. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What URL are you trying to get stats from?

Comment: No matter which URL I try to get stats, it results zero counts for facebook all the time

Answer (score 1):

If you have app in Facebook, its very simple without login, you can get the facebook counters.

Try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id={URL}&fields=engagement&access_token={your-app_id}|{your-app_secret}
```

Response will be like :

```
{
  "engagement": {
    "reaction_count": 36,
    "comment_count": 2,
    "share_count": 20,
    "comment_plugin_count": 3
  },
  "id": "https://www.example.com"
}
```

Ref : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url

To find shares number you have to address something like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt2015381%2F

You'll receive an `URL` object like this:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "10150298925420108", 
    "description": "Directed by James Gunn.  With Chris Pratt, Vin Diesel, Bradley Cooper, Zoe Saldana. A group of intergalactic criminals are forced to work together to stop a fanatical warrior from taking control of the universe.", 
    "title": "Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)", 
    "type": "video.movie", 
    "updated_time": "2015-04-22T02:19:13+0000", 
    "url": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/"
  }, 
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 4, 
    "share_count": 109631
  }, 
  "id": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/"
}
```

`share_count` field contains your info.

**upd**

In function `getCount` you have to write instead

```
 case "facebook":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = (is_array($data) ? $data[0]->total_count : $data->total_count);
                break;
```

something like this:

```
 case "facebook":
                $data = json_decode($data);
                $count = (is_array($data) ? $data["share"]->share_count : $data->share->share_count);
                break;
```

Sorry, I didn't test this, so you have to debug it and find out which format is correct.

Comment: I tried adding https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id= in the above PHP script too but it did not work. Result is zero. If I check it separately then it works but not working in PHP script above so one need to understand the PHP script above. I guess. It is far beyond my expertise knowledge

Comment: you have not only add the url, but alter the method in which you receive the shares_count - it should be somewhere in json analysis function. You need something like $result->share->share_count, and your current script probably looks for other variable, as the answer format is not the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying my best according to your suggestions but I don't know if I'll overcome this problem. I'll be posting my results after playing trial and error :)

Comment: this what I tried `"facebook"    => "http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=",` and for case facebook as you suggested in above update but it remains still zero. Other problem is if I try posting facebook url with `https://` then facebook shares option just disappears and rest of all displays ok.

Comment: Are  you sure that you post your URL escaped?

Comment: Escaped means with https? Then yes, facebook count option totally disappears if I add its graph URL with `https` and without `https (as http:// rather then https://)` it shows facebook count as zero...

Comment: I mean that like in example: they took url http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/ and send it like http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt2015381%2F

Comment: Oh, my bad :) There is no problem like that. Whenever I check any URL with these PHP scripts I hosted on a free domain as I provided in my question which is `http://codefreak.hol.es/?url=My-URL-Here` it returns all the shares of different social media platforms. It works in same way as it works on their official API. But problem at my end is facebook counts, else working perfectly fine. You can check it. I can share FTP details too :) Think I am wasting your time, will not be able to overcome this problem. Thank you so much for your kind help.